# How to put text on the widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am using the following code to gain an understanding in developing apps. However how do I put a custom text on the ball:

```
class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        # bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        # went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game
```

Can someone help me out? Trying to get some random values on the ball. It is from the standard tutorial game on the Kivy framework: Pong Game Tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main.py`, you can change your

```
class PongBall(Widget):
```

to:

```
class PongBall(Label):
```

and then, in your `pong.kv`, you can specify the desired `text`:

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    color: 0,0,0,1
    text: 'Ball'
    canvas.before:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Note the change to `canvas.before`. Without that change, the `Ellipse` will be drawn over the `text`.